# Dspace Author Indexing Insensitive Accent

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, dspace

I'm trying to reindex my dspace, and make it insensitive to accents. I need it because the resoult without the insensitive is like:

- Santos, Juan
- Sazón, Alberta
- Sánchez, Pepe

And I would like the resoults as:

- Sánchez, Pepe
- Santos, Juan
- Sazón, Alberta

I had configured the solr/search/conf/schema.xml as: 
Adding the  filter

```
        <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
      add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
      analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

After that I set down the tomcat I restart it and then I reindex with ./dspace index-discovery -b

but no change is given, can anyone help with that. Maybe other kind of config or other steps before reindexing?

I'm using: 
dspace 6

Answer (score 0):

The solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory should indeed remove diacritics so that Solr results are sorted based on the values without diacritics.

I suspect you currently don't see the expected result because you have adapted the fieldType with name "text". I believe the fieldType used by the author values in Solr is the "keywordFilter".

For example:

```
<fieldType name="keywordFilter" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <!--Treats the entire field as a single token, regardless of its content-->
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>

        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are issues in DSpace 6.3 browse pages with accents and diacritics, see e.g. http://jira.lyrasis.org/browse/DS-4034.
I'm not sure whether this can be fixed just by configuring solr.xml (adding ASCIIFoldingFilterFactor seems to remove the accents and diacritics from browse pages completely).

One solution presented in DS-4034 discussion https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/pull/2276 seems to fix the issue. Search results are shown regardless of accents. In addition, accents/diacritics are still shown as part of the lists but do not affect sorting.